# Recursive category and inner join using

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, join, recursion

I want to create recursive category.Not load any item while use join.I don't want to outer join because if a category hasn't an item, don't show.How can i solve this issue?

```
public string CategoryTree(int depth)
{
    StringBuilder sBuilder;   
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        var query = from n in db.Categories join m in db.Products on n.CatId equals m.CategoryId where n.ParentId == depth select new{n, m};
        sBuilder = new StringBuilder("<ul>");
        foreach (var q in query)
        {
            sBuilder.Append("<li>");
            sBuilder.Append("<a href='/Product/"+q.m.ProdId+">'"+q.n.Title+"</a>"+CategoryTree(q.n.CatId));
            sBuilder.Append("</li>");
        }
        sBuilder.Append("</ul>");
    }
    return sBuilder.ToString();
}

Categories
+---------+---------------+------------+
| CatId   | Title         | ParentId   |
+---------+---------------+------------+
|    1    | Electronic    |   NULL     |
+---------+---------------+------------+
|    2    | Computer      |   NULL     |
+---------+---------------+------------+
|    3    | Television    |     1      |
+---------+---------------+------------+
|    4    | Led           |     3      |
+---------+---------------+------------+
|    5    | Printer       |     2      |
+---------+---------------+------------+
|    6    | Laser Printer |     5      |
+---------+---------------+------------+

Products
+---------+---------------+------------+
| ProdId  | ProductName   | CategoryId |
+---------+---------------+------------+
|    1    | Samsung LED   |      4     |
+---------+---------------+------------+
|    2    | Sony LED TV   |      4     |
+---------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: What do you mean by recursive category? In your database schema?  Looks like you already have a recursive category

Answer (score 0):

I did a direct translation of your code into a more workable recursive function. I've split it into two to avoid instantiating multiple `DataContext` classes (which can be very slow). And I've also used Linq to XML to make the code safer to write.

```
public string CategoryTree(int? parentId)
{
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        return CategoryTree(db, parentId).ToString();
    }
}

private XElement CategoryTree(DataContext db, int? parentId)
{
    return new XElement(
        "ul", 
        from n in db.Categories
        join m in db.Products on n.CatId equals m.CategoryId
        where n.ParentId == parentId
        select new XElement(
            "li",
            new XElement(
                "a",
                new XAttribute(
                    "href",
                    "/Product/" + m.ProdId),
                n.Title),
            CategoryTree(db, n.CatId)));
}
```

Now, of course, this doesn't work because for the `parentId` equal to `null` there are no elements returned because your data doesn't have any products at that level so the join returns nothing. You must build your category tree before getting your products.

So here's what you really need to do:

```
private XElement CategoryTree(DataContext db, int? parentId)
{
    return new XElement(
        "ul", 
        from n in db.Categories
        where n.ParentId == parentId
        select new XElement(
            "li",
            new XElement(
                "span",
                n.Title),
            from m in db.Products
            where m.CategoryId == n.CatId
            select new XElement(
                "div",
                new XElement(
                    "a",
                    new XAttribute(
                        "href",
                        "/Product/" + m.ProdId),
                    m.ProductName)),
            CategoryTree(db, n.CatId)));
}
```

Now that builds the following tree:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Electronic</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Television</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Led</span>
            <div>
              <a href="/Product/1">Samsung LED</a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="/Product/2">Sony LED TV</a>
            </div>
            <ul />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Computer</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Printer</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Laser Printer</span>
            <ul />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But you don't want any category that doesn't contain products. But we don't know which don't as we build the tree so we have to prune afterwards.

Here's how I do the pruning:

```
public string CategoryTree(int? parentId)
{
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        var tree = CategoryTree(db, parentId);
        Action<string> prune = tag =>
        {
            foreach (var empty in tree
                .Descendants(tag)
                .Where(ul => !ul.Descendants("a").Any())
                .ToArray())
            {
                empty.Remove();
            }
        };
        prune("ul");
        prune("li");
        return tree.ToString();
    }
}
```

I first prune the product-free `ul` tags, but this still can leave product-free `li` tags so I have to prune those too.

Here's the final result:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Electronic</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Television</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Led</span>
            <div>
              <a href="/Product/1">Samsung LED</a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="/Product/2">Sony LED TV</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.